# Symfony2: $em-flush() is generating an error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm facing a problem while using `$em->flush ()`;
the object $education is persisted throw `$em->persist ($education)`.
The location is an entity in my project and is related to the education entity throw a many-to-one relation.

The error box Contain:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'XBundle\Entity\Education#location' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: NewYork. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `cascade={"persist"}` on the relation. E.g.:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Foo\Bundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="bar", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $foo;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the problem persist even if i added cascade={"persist"} in my entity file.

Answer (score 0):

In Doctrine 2, cascade persistence doesn't happen automatically. Instead, you need to explicitly indicate that you want it. If you are using docblock annotations to specify your DB schema, that's achieved by adding the **cascade** attribute to your **@ManyToOne** association:

```
<?php
namespace XBundle\Entity;
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Education
{
    //...

    /**        
    * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    protected $location;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer but i added cascade={"persist"} to my project and the problem persist.

Comment: /**
     * @var \Location
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location", referencedColumnName="id", cascade={"persist"})
     * })
     */
    private $location;

Comment: Does your **Location** entity have another association besides the one with **Education**? If so, could you paste the code of **Location**?

Comment: <?php
namespace X\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Location
 *
 * ORM\Table(name="location")
 * 
 */
class Location
{
    /**
     * var integer
     *
     * ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * ORM\Id
     * ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * var string
     *
     * ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

 /**
  * Get name
  *
  * return string
  */
 public function __toString()
 {
  return $this->name;
 }
//...
}

Comment: A couple of questions about your code:
1. Why do you use the _JoinColumn**s**_ (plural) annotation if you are only gonna use **one** column for the association?
2. Besides putting the **cascade={"persist"}** attribute in the **@ManyToOne** annotation, you are replicating it in the **@JoinColumn**. That's not correct. The only "cascade-like" attribute allowed in **@JoinColumn** is **onDelete** (wich is lower level/SQL DB related).

Comment: @user3110618: had you detached any entity in the request flow?

Comment: @DonCallisto: no all the entity are related. Question: can i make change in my .xml mapping?

Comment: @user3110618: detached doesn't mean that they're not related. Detached means that your entity manager didn't manage them anymore. But if you don't explicitly do it, no one will do for you ...

Comment: @DonCallisto: I use only one entity manager but the problem persist. I didn't find any correction for my problem. i tried to detach() location from education but the error message didn't change.

Comment: @user3110618 No, You didn't get what I mean.. .You have no to detach() I was only asking if it was the case :)